# I'm trying to stop this if-elif from asking further questions after the correct response is provided

Tags: python, if-statement, random

The code below asks you 4 yes/no questions, but you're only supposed to say yes to one of them. They go in the order as it shows below, but I want this to stop asking the questions as soon as the user says yes.

Example: You answer "yes" to the first question "Do you want to listen to hip-hop? (yes/no)" then it shouldn't ask the other 3 questions. If you say no to the first two questions and yes to the third it should not ask the fourth.

Are there any commands that I don't know? I tried using "else" instead of "elif" for the last command, but that didn't do what I wanted. Thanks!

```
print("We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic")
hiphop = input("Do you want to listen to hip-hop? (yes/no)")
altrock = input("Do you want to listen to alt-rock? (yes/no)")
indierock = input("Do you want to listen to indie-rock? (yes/no)")
electronic = input("Do you want to listen to electronic? (yes/no)")
hhsongs = ("Jay-Z - Feelin' It", "Notorious B.I.G. - Big Poppa", "Ice Cube - Today Was a Good Day", "Eazy-E - Boyz-n-the-Hood", "Dr. Dre - Nuthin' but a G Thang")
arsongs = ("Radiohead - Karma Police", "Beck - Loser", "Cage the Elephant - Ain't No Rest for the Wicked", "The Killers - Mr. Brightside")
irsongs = ("The Strokes - Hard to Explain", "The Spinto Band - Oh Mandy", "The Pixies - Here Comes Your Man", "Vampire Weekend - A Punk")
esongs = ("Daft Punk - One More Time", "Justice - Genesis", "Deadmau5 - Animal", "Flyring Lotus - GNG BNG")
if hiphop == "yes":
    import random
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(hhsongs))
elif altrock == "alt-rock":
    import random
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(arsongs))
elif indierock == "indie rock":
    import random
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(irsongs))
elif electronic:
    import random
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(esongs))
```

Comment: As an aside, you should `import random` once, at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your using the wrong control flow type. take a look at this implementation using a for loop with a brake statement.
it will keep asking the user for genres and then it will make a recommendation for the first genre the user wants.

```
from random import choice
genres = ["hip-hop", "alt-rock", "indie-rock", "electronic"]
songs = {
    "hip-hop": ("Jay-Z - Feelin' It", "Notorious B.I.G. - Big Poppa", "Ice Cube - Today Was a Good Day", "Eazy-E - Boyz-n-the-Hood", "Dr. Dre - Nuthin' but a G Thang"),
    "alt-rock": ("Radiohead - Karma Police", "Beck - Loser", "Cage the Elephant - Ain't No Rest for the Wicked", "The Killers - Mr. Brightside"),
    "indie-rock": ("The Strokes - Hard to Explain", "The Spinto Band - Oh Mandy", "The Pixies - Here Comes Your Man", "Vampire Weekend - A Punk"),
    "electronic": ("Daft Punk - One More Time", "Justice - Genesis", "Deadmau5 - Animal", "Flyring Lotus - GNG BNG"),
}

print("We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic")
for genre in genres:
    if input(f"do you listen to {genre}? (yes/no) ").casefold() == "yes":
        print(f"suggested: {choice(songs[genre])}")
        break
else:
    print("i don't have any recommendations for you right now.")
```

```
> python foo.py
We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic
do you listen to hip-hop? (yes/no) yes
suggested: Ice Cube - Today Was a Good Day
> python foo.py
We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic
do you listen to hip-hop? (yes/no) no
do you listen to alt-rock? (yes/no) no
do you listen to indie-rock? (yes/no) no
do you listen to electronic? (yes/no) no
i don't have any recommendations for you right now.
```

Comment: Surely a `brake` statement doesn't cause flow control in your program, it just slows it down a bit. Sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Answer (score 0):

After each request for input you can simply have an if statement:

```py
yes = False
print("We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic")
hiphop = input("Do you want to listen to hip-hop? (yes/no)")
if hiphop == 'yes':
    yes = True
if not yes:
    altrock = input("Do you want to listen to alt-rock? (yes/no)")
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to just maintain *one* variable with the choice, since the choices are mutually exclusive:

```
listenTo = None
if input("Do you want to listen to hip-hop? (yes/no)") == "yes":
    listenTo = "hiphop"
if listenTo is None and input("Do you want to listen to alt-rock? (yes/no)") == "yes":
    listenTo = "alt-rock"
if listenTo is None and input("Do you want to listen to indie-rock? (yes/no)") == "yes":
    listenTo = "indie-rock"
if listenTo is None and input("Do you want to listen to electronic? (yes/no)") == "yes":
    listenTo = "electronic"

if listenTo == "hiphop":
    blahBlahBlah()
```

That way, you can also generalise it into a re-usable function, something like:

```
# Pass in a format string with one "{}" where the chpoice should go,
# and a list of choices. Function will ask whether each choice is
# desired and, if so, return that choice. Otherwise, it will keep
# asking until all choices are exhausted, at which point it will
# return None.

def getUserChoice(fmtString, choices):
    # Process each possible choice.

    for choice in choices:
        # Ask and, if user says yes, return that choice.

        if input(fmtString.format(choice)) == "yes":
            return choice

    # Choices exhausted.

    return None

listenTo = getUserChoice("Do you want to listen to {} (yes/no)? ",
    ["hiphop", "alt-rock", "indie-rock", "electronic", "decent music like Brahms :-)"])
```

This also allows you to centralise control of the input in *one* place if, for example, you want to later modify it to handle things like upper-case answers, single-letter `Y` or `N`, or foreign languages (`si`, `oui`, and so on).

Comment: Hey, I used your first part and it worked well, but is there a chance you could give some more detail on this second part? I'm not familiar with fmtString.format, or the logic of it applied to this bottom code you provided. Thanks!

Comment: @marcellus: I've added some (probably excessive) comments to hopefully explain it better. That styler of string formatting allows you to do things like `"Three time five is {}".format(3 * 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you didn't require yes/no questions you could always have one variable that stores the choice (this has the added benefit of only requiring a user to enter something once). You can also move the import statement to the top of the code so you only need to do it once.

```
import random
    
print("We have the following genres, choose one: hip-hop, alt-rock, indie rock, electronic")

music_choice = input("Please enter the genre you want to listen to: ")

hhsongs = ("Jay-Z - Feelin' It", "Notorious B.I.G. - Big Poppa", "Ice Cube - Today Was a Good Day", "Eazy-E - Boyz-n-the-Hood", "Dr. Dre - Nuthin' but a G Thang")
arsongs = ("Radiohead - Karma Police", "Beck - Loser", "Cage the Elephant - Ain't No Rest for the Wicked", "The Killers - Mr. Brightside")
irsongs = ("The Strokes - Hard to Explain", "The Spinto Band - Oh Mandy", "The Pixies - Here Comes Your Man", "Vampire Weekend - A Punk")
esongs = ("Daft Punk - One More Time", "Justice - Genesis", "Deadmau5 - Animal", "Flyring Lotus - GNG BNG")

if music_choice == "hip-hop":
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(hhsongs))
elif music_choice == "alt-rock":
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(arsongs))
elif music_choice == "indie rock":
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(irsongs))
elif music_choice == "electronic":
    print("Suggested: " + random.choice(esongs))
else:
    print("You didn't enter a valid choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

I swear I didn't copy paxdiablo - I was in the middle of writing it when he posted.  I did it slightly differently anyway :D

```
import random
songs = {
    "hiphop": ("Jay-Z - Feelin' It", "Notorious B.I.G. - Big Poppa", "Ice Cube - Today Was a Good Day", "Eazy-E - Boyz-n-the-Hood", "Dr. Dre - Nuthin' but a G Thang"),
    "alt-rock": ("Radiohead - Karma Police", "Beck - Loser", "Cage the Elephant - Ain't No Rest for the Wicked", "The Killers - Mr. Brightside"),
    "indierock": ("The Strokes - Hard to Explain", "The Spinto Band - Oh Mandy", "The Pixies - Here Comes Your Man", "Vampire Weekend - A Punk"),
    "electronic": ("Daft Punk - One More Time", "Justice - Genesis", "Deadmau5 - Animal", "Flyring Lotus - GNG BNG")
}

answered = False
print(f'We have the following genres, choose one: {",".join(songs.keys())}')
for genre, songlist in songs.items():
    question = input(f"Do you want to listen to {genre}? (yes/no)")
    if question == "yes":
        print(f'Suggested: {random.choice(songlist)}')
        answered = True
        break
if not answered:
    print('No genre selected, guess it is the Sounds of Silence for you today')
```

Comment: Hey, this confused me when I got to the first print line. 

I'm unsure of the background of what you're doing when you write ",".join(songs.keys() and songs.items()

Are those supposed to be other modules like the way random.choice works? 

Or is "songs.keys" some kind of a call to the variable you created earlier titled "songs" - if it's that, then what does ".keys" mean/add to it?

Thanks!

Comment: The songs object is a dictionary. You can access the keys of a dictionary which in this case is the song genres using the .keys() method.  Join is a function that joins strings together with a common separator, in this case a comma. .items() method allows you to access the keywords and values of a dictionary.  So this iterates through the dictionary and retrieves the genre which is the dictionary keyword and it's corresponding value which is the list of songs for that genre and then asks you the question. If yes then you get a random choice from that list of songs.

Comment: This approach allows you to add more genres and song lists simply by adding to the dictionary, no other code changes required.